# Default behaviour of Python connections to SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, transactions, blocking

Looking for help with changing default behaviour of Python based connections to SQL server.  I have noticed this on several SQL Servers in my environment that developers/users using Python tend to keep idle connections to SQL server.  These idle connections tend to have open transactions even though they run only SELECT statements or perform reads on SQL Server database.

Since they open transactions, sometimes these idle connections tend to cause blocking.  From a SQL Server DBA standpoint, I want to ask this question about how to change default behaviour of application to NOT open transactions while running read-only queries.  I do not have any sample Python code as I am not a Python developer.  If there is any documentation, please share so I can go through and understand this to make developers aware.

Answer (score 1):

To change the behavior the python developers must set autocommit=True when they [connect](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/The-pyodbc-Module#connect) to SQL Server. eg

```
constr= 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=MyServer;DATABASE=MyDatabase;UID=MyUser;PWD=MyPassword' 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(constr, autocommit=True)
```